# media uploading to cloud using signed url interup due to some ssl certificate problems?

Tags: android, ssl, google-cloud-storage, httpsurlconnection, pre-signed-url

I am trying to upload a video file to cloud storage using a signed URL. HTTP put method is used for uploading. When I am try to connect using "HttpsUrl` connection", it returns some error like *javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed*. How can I resolve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(url_string);
httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpsUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpsUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpsUrlConnection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
httpsUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpsUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");            
httpsUrlConnection.connect();
```

stacktrace is like this

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed     
com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:390c)
com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:201)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**> Write the code for avoid SSL verification**

public class DisableSSL {

```
public void disableSSLVerification() {

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

    }};

    SSLContext sc = null;
    try {
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);

}


}
```

**add the below code before open connection**

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
DisableSSL disable = new DisableSSL();
disable.disableSSLVerification();
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```